# Laravel routing url with variable order of parameters

Tags: laravel-4

I am looking at routing to a Controller for GET URL whose parameters can vary in number or the order in which they appear in the URL. There could be many such combinations and I want to invoke the same controller action for all of these URLs

Examples of how my URLs could look like:

> 1. Route::get('route1/id/{id}',
>      'Controller1@controllerAction1');
> 2. Route::get('route1/id/{id}/name/{name}',
>      'Controller1@controllerAction1');
> 3. Route::get('route1/name/{name}',
>      'Controller1@controllerAction1');
> 4. Route::get('route1/id/{id}/name/{name}/orderby/{orderby}',
>      'Controller1@controllerAction1');
> 5. Route::get('route1/id/{id}/orderby/{orderby}',
>      'Controller1@controllerAction1');

Also in the Controller action, I ultimately want to break this query string into an array. For the second example mentioned above, I want the query string `id/{id}/name/{name}` to be converted to array `('id' => {id}, 'name' => {name})`

To invoke the same controller action for all different variations of the URLs, I have the following code in my routes.php:

```
Route::get('route1{all}', 'Controller1@controllerAction1')->where('all', '.*')
```

which seems to invoke the "`controllerAction1`" of `Controller1` for the different types of URLs mentioned above.

And in the function `controllerAction1`, I am doing

```
$route_input = Route::input('all'); 
var_dump($route_input);
which prints "/id/1/name/xyz" when I hit http://example.com/laravel/public/route1/id/1/name/xyz
```

I would like to know if:

> 1. Doing Route::get('route1{all}',
>      'Controller1@controllerAction1')->where('all', '.*') is the right
>      method to invoke same action for variable combination of get
>      parameters?
> 2. Does Laravel offer any function to convert
>      "/id/1/name/xyz" to array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'xyz') or I need to
>      write custom function?
> 3. Is there a better way to achieve my
>      requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I believe not. Plus, in this way you won't be able to understand which values are being passed.
2. Even if there is one, I think you don't actually need to pass the array. IMHO, I prefer to keep the items separate, then manipulate them from the controller. This is just my personal suggestion, but if you need an array of data, why don't you use a POST method? (the only right answer, is that you want the users to be able to save the link :P )
3. The complicated part about your request, is that you want to keep everything under the same controller action, which messes the routes. I would try this (in your `routes.php`):

```
    Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');
    Route::pattern('name', '[a-Z]+');

    Route::get('route1/{id}/{name?}/{orderby?}', 'Controller1@controllerAction1');
    Route::get('route1/{name}/{orderby?}', 'Controller1@controllerAction1');
```

In this way:

- you can have a route with just the ID, where NAME and ORDERBY are optional
- if no ID is passed, you can have a route with only NAME, where ORDERBY is optional

Note how this is different from your URLs: it's much more complicated to put the routes as you wrote them `id/{id}/name/{name}`, than in the way I proposed `{id}/{name}`. If you need them exactly your way, why don't you call the links passing the variables from the GET function as follows? `http://www.yoursite.com/route1?id=xxxx&name=yyyy&orderBy=zzzz`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I liked your suggestions. I would try http://www.yoursite.com/route1?id=xxxx&name=yyyy&orderBy=zzzz format.

Comment: @user3402821 you are welcome :) can you accept the answer please? Otherwise others will waste time answering

Comment: I am going to follow yoursite.com/route1?id=xxxx&name=yyyy&orderBy=zzzz format. thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

To have the route parameters convert from a set of individual parameters to an array that contains all the parameters in Laravel 5, you can call this from the Controller:

`$routeParameters = $this->getRouter()->getCurrentRoute()->parameters()`

For the route definition
`Route::get('route1/id/{id}/name/{name}', 'Controller1@controllerAction1');`
 if a user hits the route with the following: `/route1/id/2/name/john`

`$routeParameters` would equal
`array(id => 2, name => 'john')`